# Сортировка категории wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Приветствую!
Есть цикл категории

```
<ul class="filter_country">
    <?php foreach (get_terms('country') as $cat) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'country'); ?>"> <?php echo $cat->name; ?> </a><span><?php echo $cat->count; ?></span></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Как добавить сортировка по $cat->count ?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функцию `get_terms` можно передавать массив аргументов, в том числе параметр сортировки:

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
  'taxonomy' => 'country', 
  'orderby' => 'count',
  'order' => 'ASC' // по возрастанию (значение по умолчанию) или DESC - по убыванию 
));
```